# How to fix null imei and mac address?

Tags: rom-flashing, imei, mac-address, google-pixel-6

I was messing around with the devinfo partition of my pixel 6 pro,but I made a backup before. As a result it was stuck in a bootloop, so I restored devinfo's backup using fastboot, all good so far, phone boots well and everything is normal, unless for wifi and bluetooth. they can't be turned on. mac address is "unavailable". IMEI as well is a bunch of zeros. I don't know what's wrong, I did not touch the efs partition at all. does anybody have any idea of what went wrong?